# swapping user defined consecutive values in R

Tags: r, vector

Given a vector, I wanted to swap the values when particular elements were consecutive.

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

I want to make a rule, if "B" comes before "C", then swap the values.

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
res
[1] "A" "C" "B"
```

If "T" comes before "U",

```
y <- c("T", "U", "X", "A", "U")
res2
[1] "U" "T" "X" "A" "U"
```

More broadly for multiple matches also. Here if "D" is directly before "B",

```
z <- c("A", "D", "B", "X", "D", "B")
res3
[1] "A" "B" "D" "X" "B" "D"
```

Comment: `This forum` What forum? This is a Q&A site.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a network of **forums**; it is a network of question and answer sites.  This is neither a question or an answer.  If you wish to share this, please do so in the question-and-answer format (post a self-answer to an *actual* question).  If you're looking for improving the code you've shared here, presuming it works exactly as intended, you can consider posting the working code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Wow that forum word was the wrong language. I fully understand that this is not a literal forum. I participate on this site regularly and am well aware of the format. I meant it in the broader sense of a site where `R` users can ask and learn. I have seen many code improvement posts and have even helped others on them myself. I will continue to help and ask questions. And even share answers that I stumbled upon in the hopes that someone else can use it or improve upon it.

Comment: Hey, "forum" is fine by me, but you might want to know that "a check on progress" actually means something that stops or slows down progress :) See definition #3 here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/check

Comment: If it wasn't for this site, I wouldn't be anywhere near where I'm at with 'R'. I'm learning the mix of creativity and knowledge that makes a good analyst. It makes me better at my job. I will be more thoughtful about 'helper' posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like this isn't exactly elegant, but should work

```
swap<-function(x, pair) {
    stopifnot(length(pair)==2)
    a1 <- which(x==pair[1])
    a2 <- which(x==pair[2])
    if (length(a1<-a1[a1 %in% (a2-1)])) {
        x[a1] <- pair[2]
        x[a1+1] <- pair[1]
    }
    x
}

z <- c("A", "D", "B", "X", "D", "B")
swap(z, c("Z","D"))    #no change
# [1] "A" "D" "B" "X" "D" "B"
swap(z, c("A","D"))    #one change
# [1] "D" "A" "B" "X" "D" "B"
swap(z, c("D","B"))    #multi-change
# [1] "A" "B" "D" "X" "B" "D"
```

Comment: this works great. I tried one, but yours works in more cases.

Answer (score 1):

I broke it up into two different functions

```
switchup <- function(vec, first=1, second=2) {
  vec[c(first,second)] <- vec[c(second,first)]
  return(vec)
}
swap.match <- function(v, source.pattern, stray.pattern) {
  host   <- which(v==source.pattern)
  target <- which(v==stray.pattern)
  hits <- target[which(v[host-1]==stray.pattern)]
  hits <- as.vector(na.omit(hits))
  switchup(v, hits, hits+1)
}

swap.match(x, "C", "B")
[1] "A" "C" "B"
swap.match(y, "U", "T")
[1] "U" "T" "X" "A" "U"
swap.match(z, "B", "D")
[1] "A" "B" "D" "X" "B" "D"
```

Mr.Flick's solution works in more cases than this.